# Node.js spawn not working with quotes inside argument

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I'm trying to run this command with spawn

```
var args = ['-ss','00:00:15','-i',storage_path + doc.file_name,'-vframes','1','-vf','"scale='+size*2+':ih*'+size*2+'/iw,crop='+size+':'+size+'"','-f','image2','-q:v','5',storage_path + output_name];

var command = spawn('ffmpeg', args);
```

The issue seems to be with this part here: `'"scale='+size*2+':ih*'+size*2+'/iw,crop='+size+':'+size+'"'`

When I log the args, this is what I get:

`[ '-ss',
'00:00:15',
'-i',
'/a/video.mp4',
'-vframes',
'1',
'-vf',
'"scale=150:ih*150/iw, crop=75:75"',
'-f',
'image2',
'-q:v',
'5',
'/a/75.jpg' ]`

If I take that, and do `.join(' ')`, I get the command: 
`-ss 00:00:15 -i /a/video.mp4 -vframes 1 -vf "scale=150:ih*150/iw, crop=75:75" -f image2 -q:v 5 /a/75.jpg`

When I run ffmpeg with this, all is good.

Any ideas how to format this for spawn arguments?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use quotes for `vf`:

```
'scale='+size*2+':ih*'+size*2+'/iw,crop='+size+':'+size
```